# loop does not work. could not find the symantic error

Tags: java

I tried using a loop to get a proper desired input from the user. The loop just doesn't stop. I brainstormed for a while but could not patch the bug.

```
 char choice;
 System.out.println("Below is a auto generated description for your property.Is it okay    for you? (y/n)");
    choice = sc.next().charAt(0);

    for(;(choice!='y' || choice !='Y' || choice!='n' || choice !='N' );)
    {
        choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Please enter 'y' or 'n'.");
    }
    // ... other codes ... //
```

Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: I think the sc.next().charAt(0); has to do something with the error. But was not sure so I did not mention it in the question. :)

Comment: Shouldn't `||` be `&&`? Take a look at it this way, if `choice` is `y` then it is not `Y` (and vice-versa) so condition `choice!='y' || choice !='Y'` will always be true.

Comment: I think you want to loop as long as choice is not y AND not Y AND not n AND not N. As soon as either of them is entered (OR), you want to end the loop. So you should use `&&` instead of each of the `||`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
choice != 'y' || choice != 'Y'
```

The above test will always be true. If choice is y, then `choice != 'Y'` is true, and the whole condition is thus also true. If choice is Y, then `choice != 'y'` is true, and the whole condition is thus also true.

You want `&&` instead of `||`.

Also, `for (; condition;)` is more readable when written as `while (condition)`.

Comment: @user3519322 You can shorten the condition further by converting the text to either uppercase or lowercase and include only those checks in your condition :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    for(; !(choice=='y' || choice =='Y' || choice=='n' || choice =='N' ) ;)
    {
        choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Please enter 'y' or 'n'.");
    }
```

Just add a `!`. In my opinion, `while` loop is more suitable here.

```
while(user did not enter y or n){
 // loop
}
```

Comment: De-morgan disagrees with you.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Is he happy now ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

you should use && operator inside for or while loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char choice;
 System.out.println("Below is a auto generated description for your property.Is it okay    for you? (y/n)");
choice = sc.next().charAt(0);

while(choice!='y' && choice !='Y' && choice!='n' && choice !='N' ){
    System.out.println("Please enter 'y' or 'n'.");
     choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
}
```